# i want to get the value of ng-value in ng-model so i can use the data in controller part. Is it possible or is there any other way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-value

> Code in html

```
<div ng-repeat="cityobj in cityData" class="tabledata">
           <input type="text" ng-value="{{cityobj.temp.humidity}}" ng-model="humidity">
            <div>
```

> In controller

```
console.log("The value in textfield is",$scope.humidity);
```

> It always give undefined output

Comment: "It always give undefined output". What does it give as output?

Comment: i mean in console it gives the value in $scope.humidity is undefined

Comment: same `ng-model` for everybody?

Comment: You are binding all item&#39;s humidity in only 1 var. Maybe it is the problem. Or maybe the sentence (console.log) get executed before the html is rendering

Comment: @Hitmands Yes for same body

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ng-value since you already using ng-model

```
<div ng-repeat="cityobj in cityData" class="tabledata">
       <input type="text ng-model="cityobj.temp.humidity">
 <div>
```

and then it should work

```
console.log("The value in textfield is",$scope.cityData[passindex].cityobj.temp.humidity");
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app =angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

$scope.cityData = [{
  "city": "Klimovsk",
  "temp": {
     "humidity":2
  }
}, {
  "city": "Shalakusha",
   "temp": {
     "humidity":5
  }
}];

$scope.print =function(cityObj){
 console.log(cityObj.temp.humidity);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="cityobj in cityData" class="tabledata">
       <input type="text" ng-model="cityobj.temp.humidity">
       <button ng-click=print(cityobj)>PRINT</button>
 <div>
 </body>
```

Comment: So why would you store the value on ng-model if in the log you access it from the main object?

Comment: @Doblel that is just a sample to show you need to have different ng-model for each input